# Map over an array of objects to create a table in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a react js app the use api severs to get a json their are no errors here is the

```
[
  {
    "_id": "596fd78716053511f42188e9",
    "Access_Token": "ogdb33RJ0el2AZ1z1vNCvRy7hF96oIMLh_xLI6rMPmykXbfdimW_aBpC6dZOAnodQels8AeEXcANJIQMxeANng2",
    "Refresh_Token": "G63-wu-RpG0xyQTePCt5XuzbGC6fF8Wbfsr1z_VoiT1fplso4qugOCO_ghHiNCUXJJfajc2iPZaPCEIPVb6rbRtxXxLxpGi7Xud3UqLph2eO9tGeO9538Rz-2vg7DiqqcQ8e8O8TvW8suLxLBHNO8QHCwHxGNFfVNZ4CfEo2fV-6MxmrNeh1S01g1TT0IKAKZQ1XLop6X0zKAbScia4rdIwBDHoRtyZzqzPN5uwmhg8MUcBsQ0cwQOMb3s3eMuWKWP1dm76Otyt5ZWAgLGp4JMOjmSB0w6Rcy48ckA2qIxTsosHYUg7Y5ndT9JyuQRpunsxA2",
    "Character_ID": "92935856",
    "Character_Name": "MI Alar",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "596fd79016053511f42188ea",
    "Access_Token": "b1pWTaL12_dK6-wR3jTdthli4noDKGLfO3iTcQ1e40J8JCEQYQ6Bn9VV7lIoJShvUJ1ojKRpXgmq1pOQyGBlxQ2",
    "Refresh_Token": "cvleJ32OTTOremynstuSouDb_Vvym__O2iiJHWdTY-D2Pir1lGfGKQFyvyoDTIbf7JL0nVmuzkDdanzeJad4khNZu0SjsfGms-q3FwA8myBoYZ6UJTjPqu2GtBfnPDLN0rVbbjOkK4SooXlBSEqn6YU_zAUsVo5SYa1TA5lAQLQkJY2B_gfs2I5l9lbvNGcf4K3X6IWO4GFMQDk5nfV--m7G-3EoRWdaLCvf5eUy_TAF2V-oq3c2CvVp_SBTFaXPDM8NPGpt7mjFxvwkHCYlVGCm8XeUHKIZfiLazZEJ9mRW4g2pfhZbRAXEpTLpWVY8N7CG0vd8J7w2",
    "Character_ID": "390786416",
    "Character_Name": "shawn313",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "596fd79916053511f42188eb",
    "Access_Token": "SwjGVPd5AKMtZGVA1ei8VEG3GZ1XJZx6ErGrQO3fr0S2zKHJL_j4490kRQ0l_cBOgaN5FrQY2QAtTR2OUYGlfg2",
    "Refresh_Token": "aPvIXyA8Xx--UJixHJ1T3KGkhN6gfA1OdBorjOj_JGiHz3eFupv3DhchmbHpDGN_5GIFKspHr5xQZhLjxuiBo0RPmdRlLFpblGwv5X7i_6gpXoMV4_scLQ_X7CE8HSAtXuSMxyJy7GotxTgtHvBhFCDHrI9Py1G1g5BMZ6aGFXYA2CR9uXWIp-y5E-djAk7L4235Ows4t6Ow0kcHxWx7EX6OQkrwfZpqUOjDMfdS5DM-du2bzoQ2",
    "Character_ID": "812900457",
    "Character_Name": "shawn312",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

code

```
  import React from 'react'
  import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  import * as chrrdActions from '../../Redux/Chrrd'

  const Apis = props => (props.ChrList.list.map((item, i) => {
     return <tr key={item.objecj._id}>
    <td>{item._id}</td>
    <td>{item.Character_Name}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Character_ID}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Access_Token}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Refresh_Token}</td>
</tr>
 }));

const ChrTable = props => (
<div>
    <table style={{ 'height': '40%', 'width': '600px', 'display': 'block' }}>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th> Id </th>
                <th> Character Name </th>
                <th> Character ID</th>
                <th> Access Token </th>
                <th> Refresh Token</th>
            </tr>
            {Apis}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 )

   export default connect(state => ({
ChrList: state.ChrList
   }),
{
    ...chrrdActions
}
  )(ChrTable)
```

here is what the page shows 
[image]

im not sure what is happen but i use redux to store the json to a state to be used can post the code for redux if need. the call works fine and passing the json works as show in the redux logs in the picture

Comment: Please check your spelling, punctuation and grammar. It makes your question harder to decipher.

Comment: sorry have a learning learning disability  so spelling and all that is not that good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i got it to work

```
import React from 'react'
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as chrrdActions from '../../Redux/Chrrd'
import * as ViewChrActions from '../../Redux/ViewChr'

class Chr extends React.Component {
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.callingApi();
    this.props.updatePf('failed');
    this.props.updateSkL('failed');
    this.props.updateId('');
    this.props.updateCid('');
    this.props.updateAt('');
    this.props.updateRt('');
    this.props.updateSk('');
}

Charview(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
    this.props.updateId(a1);
    this.props.updateCid(a2);
    this.props.updateAt(a3);
    this.props.updateRt(a4);
    this.props.callingApiPre();
    this.props.changePage();
};

render() {
    if (this.props.ChrList.Loading === 'false') {
        const apis = this.props.ChrList.list.map((item, i) => {
            return <tr key={item._id}><td className="ellipsis">{item._id}      </td>
                <td>{item.Character_Name}</td>
                <td className="ellipsis">{item.Character_ID}</td>
                <td className="ellipsis">{item.Access_Token}</td>
                <td className="ellipsis">{item.Refresh_Token}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.Charview(item._id,    item.Character_ID, item.Access_Token, item.Refresh_Token)} className="button_t"  >View</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        });

        return <div  >
            <table className='table'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Id </th>
                        <th> Character Name </th>
                        <th> Character ID</th>
                        <th> Access Token </th>
                        <th> Refresh Token</th>
                        <th> Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    {apis}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    } else {
        return <div  >
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        </div>
    }
}
}

 export default connect(state => ({
ChrList: state.ChrList,
ViewChr: state.ViewChr
}),
{
    ...chrrdActions,
    ...ViewChrActions,
    changePage: () => push('/vchr')
}
)(Chr)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Apis` is a `functional stateless component`, you need to `pass the props` to it and call it like a `component`. Also it must return a single element so wrap the content of your map within a `tbody` tag and it should work

```
 import React from 'react'
  import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  import * as chrrdActions from '../../Redux/Chrrd'

  const Apis = props => <tbody>{props.ChrList.list.map((item, i) => {
     return <tr key={item.objecj._id}>
    <td>{item._id}</td>
    <td>{item.Character_Name}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Character_ID}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Access_Token}</td>
    <td className="ellipsis">{item.Refresh_Token}</td>
</tr>
 })}</tbody>;

const ChrTable = props => (
<div>
    <table style={{ 'height': '40%', 'width': '600px', 'display': 'block' }}>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th> Id </th>
                <th> Character Name </th>
                <th> Character ID</th>
                <th> Access Token </th>
                <th> Refresh Token</th>
            </tr>
            <Apis {...props}/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 )

   export default connect(state => ({
ChrList: state.ChrList
   }),
{
    ...chrrdActions
}
  )(ChrTable)
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this answer