# how to get data from json and display in the table

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux

```
const CustomerInfo = [
    { id: "1", value: "9940572756", lastRecharge: "349", lastCallDuration: "09:58", lastCalledNumber: "9478369258", status: "Active" },
    { id: "2", value: "9874563210", lastRecharge: "110", lastCallDuration: "01:01:13", lastCalledNumber: "9632587410", status: "In Active" },
    { id: "3", value: "9517530258", lastRecharge: "500", lastCallDuration: "02:40", lastCalledNumber: "9362580147", status: "Active" }
]
```

**i need this to be display in a form where i have a submit button and also need to show this in a table when called value as a phone number**

Comment: What is you question here? Do you want us to help you creating a table showing these customer infos?

Comment: Hope you will find out the solution in the link below
[Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427163/map-over-an-array-of-objects-to-create-a-table-in-reactjs)

Answer (score -1):

render() {

```
return (
  <table>
  <tbody>{this.CustomerInfo.map(function(item, key) {

           return (
              <tr key = {key}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.value}</td>
                  <td>{item.lastRecharge}</td>
                  <td>{item.lastCallDuration}</td>
                  <td>{item.lastCalledNumber}</td>
              </tr>
            )

         })}</tbody>
   </table>
)
```

}